# I have a problem understanding the logic of how to work with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, height, nslayoutconstraint

Here is my repository of the project:

https://github.com/alonsd/MoviesApi

The reason I am giving here the entire project is because the problems lies inside a .xib file and is not a code issue, therefor I think this would be the better way of me getting help for this issue.

I am facing the following issue when trying to populate a custom cell inside a table view from some data that I have.

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

So I looked for solutions over this site and came across a nice debugging way to figure out what is wrong, I made an extension that overrides the description var of NSLayoutDescription and prints out the id and the constant for faster and better understanding where the problem lies. So apparently the error goes away once I delete the height and weight from my img inside my .xib file, but that would make the image disappear completely from the .xib. What is the problem specifically with the way I did my layout? I tried also to use "reset to suggested constraints" on my .xib file and it makes the error go away but it also makes every cell height to be huge once I scroll up and down.

And for another issue I am facing - I think I am not sure about how constraints work. That is because when you look at my xib file you can see a major space between the image and the right end of the cell, but in the list itself there is nothing so I am really confused about that.

This is the image of the simulator with the tableview -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c71DQ.jpg

and this is the image of my .xib file with the spaces that actually do not appear in the simulator -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSK5E.jpg

(I could not figure out how to put them directly in the post)

Comment: you set your constraints wrongly and stackview also need some constraints

Comment: Which constraint is the wrong one? and which stackview is the one missing constraints?

Comment: You also set wrong constraint in your detail View

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about what is wrong?

Comment: Try @Sh_Khan answer it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Remove width & height constraints here

[image]

2- Remove containerView leading constraint here

[image]
3- Add a trailing constraint to the stackview

4- Add a value to the stackview leading constant

[image]

5- select all labels and adjust vertical content hugging to 1000

[image]

6- select the textContainer stack and set spacing to say 20

Comment: Its not working, as it will increase height of cell when scroll through.

Comment: mondi is corrent, this solution creates 2 problems - 

1 - the  height of the cell is increased while scrolling
2  - I get some small margin between the image end and the right end of the cell

Comment: I followed your solution all the way to number 6 and this is what I got so far: 


https://imgur.com/Mb00evN

Comment: it works without the cell suddently getting higher height when scrolling and no error in the console but it seems really "squished" together so I would rather it would be a little bit higher. also the margins at the right from the picture needs to be taken care of. 

I would very much appreicate if you could explain what were my mistakes and what you did so far. thanks!

Comment: if you could help me address this issue it would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

In general you should have 4 constrains. I had the same problem with you for a while and for me the best solution that works the best is using percentage for height or width and then aspect ratio. For example the height of the element is going to be 20% of the view and then I use aspect ratio for the width etc.
Also don't use stackView to all 5 elements. Leave the Movie Image outside the stackView.

Comment: when you are saying 4 constraints you mean each view must have 4 constraints regarding of what stack they are inside? or the total amount of constraints for each storyboard/xib file should be 4 constraints? neither of them seems logical to me but I hope you can clarify.

Comment: You should have constrains for height,width, x position and y position for each element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you used StackView but stackveiws also need some constraints.[image]

[image]

Here is the constraints I used to get the result
I put 4 elements in stack view and give image to leading top width and height

Comment: Yes Sir it will but the OP said it will increase the cell height but this solution won't increase the height

Comment: it should increase the cell height if needed

Comment: It won't increase the cell height I think because I already defined height of labels and image

Comment: this solution seems a bit overkill for my requirements
I will update you for what I have done so far - 
I have cleared all constraints and only added 4 constraints to the main container and I have still stuck understand what causes the issue of the cell height going much bigger - the only solution to this is giving it a fixed height but then I get the error of unable to satisfy constraints in the console.

Comment: I have figured out how to fix this issue already but thank you anyway very much